# Prevent Tkinter window to pop up once is called only once

Tags: python, class, tkinter, toplevel, gtkbutton

I have a small test Tkinter window with Labels and Entries in a file called "customer.py"
I created another file "button_test.py" with a super simple tkinter window with only one button to call "customer.py"

The button calls 'customer.py" with no problem but If I click the button again over andover. Keeps popping up the same window. I could probably add some conditions over there maybe but I would like to know if there is a better way to prevent that. I see it also happens with the "Tk TopLevel"

I thank you for your help and time Comrades.

*customer.py*

```
from tkinter import *


class OFFLINE():
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.win = window
        self.win.title("Emails")
        
        frame = LabelFrame(self.win, text = 'CUSTOMER INFORMATION')
        frame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, )    
        
        Label(frame, text = "Case Number").grid(column = 0, row = 1)
        self.Case_box = Entry(frame).grid(column = 1, row = 1)
        
        Label(frame, text = "Customer Name").grid(column = 0, row = 2)
        self.name_box = Entry(frame).grid(column = 1, row = 2)
        
        Label(frame, text = "Phone number").grid(column = 0, row = 3)
        self.phone_box = Entry(frame).grid(column = 1, row = 3)

        Label(frame, text = "Email").grid(column = 0, row =4)
        self.email_box = Entry(frame).grid(column =1, row = 4)
        
        
        
def main():
    root = Tk()
    application = OFFLINE(root)
    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*button_test.py*

```
import customer
from tkinter import *

offline = customer

window = Tk()

button = Button(window, text = "Click Me", command =offline.main)


button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `button['state'] = 'disabled'` ?

Comment: you should use `Tk` only to create main window - for second you should use `Toplevel`. And you should use only one `mainloop()`. If you have two `mainloop` then some tkinter's variables may work incorrectly and they may have wrong values.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable button

```
button['state'] = 'disabled'
```

and later enable it

```
button['state'] = 'normal'
```

Or you can use `.grab_set()` to make `modal` window and first window will not get key/mouse events.

---

Minimal working code

```
from tkinter import *

def set_disabled():
    button1['state'] = 'disabled'

def set_normal():
    button1['state'] = 'normal'
    
window = Tk()

button1 = Button(window, text = "Click Me", command=set_disabled)
button1.pack()

button2 = Button(window, text = "Next Me", command=set_normal)
button2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Example with second window.

It shows how to do it with `Toplevel()` instead od second `Tk()` and without second `mainloop()

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def close_window():
    top_window.destroy()
    
    button_open['state'] = 'normal'
    
def open_window():
    global top_window  # to keep value in external variable
    global button_close  # to keep value in external variable
    
    button_open['state'] = 'disabled'

    top_window = tk.Toplevel(window)
    
    label = tk.Label(top_window, text="New Window")
    label.pack()
    
    button_close = tk.Button(top_window, text = "Close", command=close_window)
    button_close.pack()
        
# --- main ---

window = tk.Tk()

button_open = tk.Button(window, text="Open", command=open_window)
button_open.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Example with `grab_set()` to make window `modal`

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def open_window():

    top_window = tk.Toplevel(window)
    top_window.grab_set()
    
    label = tk.Label(top_window, text="New Window")
    label.pack()
    
    button_close = tk.Button(top_window, text = "Close", command=top_window.destroy)
    button_close.pack()
        
# --- main ---

window = tk.Tk()

button_open = tk.Button(window, text="Open", command=open_window)
button_open.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guid for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

You can *simulate singleton feature* using class as below:

*customer.py*

```py
from tkinter import *

__all__ = ['main']

class OFFLINE():
    ...

class _SingletonWin(Toplevel):
    _instance = None

    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kw)
        self.form = OFFLINE(self)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_destroy)

    @classmethod
    def on_destroy(cls):
        if cls._instance:
            cls._instance.destroy()
            cls._instance = None

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = cls()
        return cls._instance

def main():
    return _SingletonWin.get_instance()
```

Then whenever `main()` is called, only one instance of the toplevel will be shown.